# Mic supposedly on, for/by the keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, microphone

Now and then on my MacBook Air, the orange dot is on, as if the mic is in use. When I click it, this is what it shows:

[image]

I have not used the dictation feature since I restarted my Mac, and I don't have a third-party keyboard app installed either.

I tried hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, to no avail. (I have my Mac set to use the function keys, so hitting F5 alone doesn't toggle the microphone.)

Here are my dictation settings:
[image]

Also: I am unable to use dictation if I want to, since <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't do anything.

What could this mean? How do I turn the mic off?

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean by *"I have my Mac set to use the function keys, so hitting F5 alone doesn't toggle the microphone"*. Looking at your screenshot I fail to see why you're trying to use the `Fn`+`F5` combination? By default users have to press the `Fn` key twice to use dictation, so you need to clarify if/how you've changed that.

Comment: @Monomeeth , thanks. F5 is the key that corresponds to dictation on my MacBook Air. Because I have the system set to use F5 (and the others) as function keys, I have to hit the FN key and F5 to access the "extra functionality". This is the same as hitting F5 for someone who hasn't customized the system to use function keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am late, but for the sake of people in the future who might come across the same problem, check two things:

1. If you have opened the System Settings window, close it.
2. If you are using multiple user accounts, check if the other accounts are using microphone. If other accounts have the System Settings window open, close it.

Comment: Thanks, Dimen. I know that #2 didn't apply, but I wouldn't be surprised if I had the Settings window open. I'm selecting your answer as "the" answer, since it's the only one 